# Kivy set video options in KV file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make the video repeat in Kivy, and I have found this command:

```
options={'eos': 'loop'})
```

However this is for the python file. How can I define the same thing in KV file?

Right now in KV I have:

```
Video:
    source:"./112.mp4"
    state:"play"
    eos:"loop"   <---- not working
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it uses the same principle as e.g. `pos_hint`, therefore try this:

```
Video:
    source:"./112.mp4"
    state:"play"
    options: {'eos': 'loop'}
```